# Store all information about the text of a richtextbox and reconstruct it- c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

Is there a way to store all of the information about the text in a `richtextbox` (*colors, sizes, fonts, etc*) and reconstruct it in another `richtextbox`, **which is not in the same form or project?**

For example, I have a richtextbox which its text contains multiple fonts and colors, and some lines are centered, and I want to reconstruct it in another richtextbox.

**I added that the new richtextbox is not in the same project, so i need to restore the information somewhere (for example, even in a string or a file).**

Comment: Do you mean the text _and_ the formatting, or only the formatting (colors, fonts...)?

Comment: @HeinzKessler the text and the formatting

Comment: Heinz' answer pointed out: _you can do with it whatever you can do with strings_ , so it should be trivial to persist the Rtf string into other projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To copy the text and formatting from one richTextBox to another, simply use:

```
richtextBox2.Rtf = richtextBox1.Rtf;
```

The [Rtf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.rtf?view=netframework-4.8) property is simply a string, so you can do with it whatever you can do with strings.

Comment: How are you going to do that, if they are from two different projects?

Comment: @BogdanDoicin I will write it into a file or send it through a socket.

Comment: @HeinzKessler Is there an event for the rtf changing?

Comment: No such event beyond the TextChanged. Many or most formatting is done by changing the selection first, so Selection'changed may elp. Who is doing the changes? Not your code??

Comment: "Different project" means nothing. If the two projects end up being part of the same application, then you can use a totally different approach then when the two controls live on different continents. However, since rtf is nothing than strings, you can send these strings like any other string. Therefore the question here is answered, and for the rest of his problem, he will find answers elsewhere in SO.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with the following steps

assume we have two projects

the first is **WinFormApp1**  and  the second is **WinFormApp2**

1. Save the `RTF` of the `RichTextBox1` in **WinFormApp1** in a text file

   In **WinFormApp1**

   ```
       const string path = @"D:\RichTextBox\Example.txt";

       var rtbInfo = richTextBox1.Rtf;

       if (!File.Exists(path))
       {
           File.Create(path);
           TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(path);
           textWriter.WriteLine(rtbInfo);
           textWriter.Close();
       }
       else if (File.Exists(path))
       {
            File.WriteAllText(path, rtbInfo);
       }
   ```
2. Read the data from the text file and assigned to `RTF` of the `RichTextBox1` in **WinFormApp2**

   In **WinFormApp2**

   ```
   private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       const string path = @"D:\RichTextBox\Example.txt";

       if (File.Exists(path))
       {
           richTextBox1.Rtf = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);
       }
   }
   ```